# Xvfb in Selenium: RenderCompositorSWGL failed to display the default frame buffer, no dt

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

When running Java code or starting the browser manually via the command line, I get this:

```
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
```

java code:

```
    src/main/java/com/app/HelloWorld.java
package com.app;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.setHeadless(true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
                driver.get("google.com");
                driver.quit();
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ java -jar target/maven-assembly-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Hello world
1654623057269   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:47197
1654623057635   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "49021" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "--remote-allow-origins" "http://localhost:49021/" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile9PwHpR"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1654623058388   Marionette      INFO    Marionette enabled
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
console.warn: SearchSettings: "get: No settings file exists, new profile?" (new NotFoundError("Could not open the file at /tmp/rust_mozprofile9PwHpR/search.json.mozlz4", (void 0)))
DevTools listening on ws://localhost:49021/devtools/browser/16221e6b-f640-4586-ae8e-27eb3d3a32c2
1654623061606   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 33863
1654623061679   RemoteAgent     WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "javascriptEnabled" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platform" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Jun 08, 2022 12:31:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.W3CCapabilityKeysValidator validateCapability
WARNING: Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "platformVersion" which is an invalid capability. Please update to W3C Syntax: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Malformed URL: URL constructor: google.com is not a valid URL.
Build info: version: '4.2.0', revision: '86eb611648'
System info: host: 'HostNameMax', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.0-9-amd64', java.version: '17.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [63e7e772-0098-4714-adac-8cac42d15770, get {url=google.com}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 91.8.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20220330151638, moz:debuggerAddress: localhost:49021, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.31.0, moz:headless: true, moz:processID: 1103, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofile9PwHpR, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 5.10.0-9-amd64, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:49021/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 85.0, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 63e7e772-0098-4714-adac-8cac42d15770
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:566)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:329)
        at com.app.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:12)
```

I also tried using xvfb-run, but it didn't help. The error is the same for all browsers. What can I do? There is no graphical shell on the server.
Upd: firefox --headless and chromium --headless output the same error.

Comment: Not sure about the render problem, but part of your stacktrace involves the URL... try with " https : // www.google.com".  (There's some validation for URL's passed to get() method... so add https: // and www... probably just need "www.")

Comment: Thank. It remains to find a solution to the rendering problem, it dragged on for a long time